# wso2 app server (carbon) startup error

Tags: java, environment, wso2

I am trying to start up the WSO2 app server and get this error. I have nothing deployed except I set up some data services.  It was working fine and now it gives this error.  I am on Windows 8.1 and running Java 1.7.0_75.  I thought I read somewhere about a setup.conf file being corrupted but can't find that article of this file anymore.  I do have Java 1.8 on my machine but disabled that in windows and also made sure the java_home is set correctly.  Thanks for your help in advance.

```
[2015-07-06 10:12:19,672]  INFO {org.wso2.carbon.core.internal.CarbonCoreActivator} -  Starting WSO2 Carbon...
[2015-07-06 10:12:19,680]  INFO {org.wso2.carbon.core.internal.CarbonCoreActivator} -  Operating System : Windows 8.1 6.3, amd64
[2015-07-06 10:12:19,680]  INFO {org.wso2.carbon.core.internal.CarbonCoreActivator} -  Java Home        : D:\Java\jdk1.7.0_75\jre
[2015-07-06 10:12:19,680]  INFO {org.wso2.carbon.core.internal.CarbonCoreActivator} -  Java Version     : 1.7.0_75
[2015-07-06 10:12:19,680]  INFO {org.wso2.carbon.core.internal.CarbonCoreActivator} -  Java VM          : Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM 24.75-b04,Oracle Corporation
[2015-07-06 10:12:19,680]  INFO {org.wso2.carbon.core.internal.CarbonCoreActivator} -  Carbon Home      : D:/development/wso2as-5.2.1
[2015-07-06 10:12:19,680]  INFO {org.wso2.carbon.core.internal.CarbonCoreActivator} -  Java Temp Dir    : D:/development/wso2as-5.2.1/tmp
[2015-07-06 10:12:19,680]  INFO {org.wso2.carbon.core.internal.CarbonCoreActivator} -  User             : Dean, en-US, America/New_York
[2015-07-06 10:12:19,752]  WARN {org.wso2.carbon.core.bootup.validator.util.ValidationResultPrinter} -  The running OS : Windows 8.1 is not a tested Operating System for running WSO2 Carbon
[2015-07-06 10:12:19,752]  WARN {org.wso2.carbon.core.bootup.validator.util.ValidationResultPrinter} -  The default keystore (wso2carbon.jks) is currently being used. To maximize security when deploying to a production environment, configure a new keystore with a unique password in the production server profile.
[2015-07-06 10:12:19,800]  INFO {org.wso2.carbon.databridge.agent.thrift.AgentHolder} -  Agent created !
[2015-07-06 10:12:19,816]  INFO {org.wso2.carbon.databridge.agent.thrift.internal.AgentDS} -  Successfully deployed Agent Client
[2015-07-06 10:12:21,048]  INFO {org.wso2.carbon.registry.core.jdbc.EmbeddedRegistryService} -  Configured Registry in 43ms
[2015-07-06 10:12:21,110]  INFO {org.wso2.carbon.registry.core.internal.RegistryCoreServiceComponent} -  Registry Mode    : READ-WRITE
[2015-07-06 10:12:21,918]  INFO {org.wso2.carbon.user.core.internal.UserStoreMgtDSComponent} -  Carbon UserStoreMgtDSComponent activated successfully.
[2015-07-06 10:12:30,565] FATAL {org.wso2.carbon.core.init.CarbonServerManager} -  WSO2 Carbon initialization Failed
org.apache.axiom.om.OMException: javax.xml.stream.XMLStreamException: ParseError at [row,col]:[31,21]
Message: Invalid byte 1 of 1-byte UTF-8 sequence.
    at org.apache.axiom.om.impl.builder.StAXOMBuilder.next(StAXOMBuilder.java:296)
    at org.apache.axiom.om.impl.llom.OMSerializableImpl.build(OMSerializableImpl.java:78)
    at org.apache.axiom.om.impl.llom.OMElementImpl.build(OMElementImpl.java:722)
    at org.apache.axis2.util.XMLUtils.toOM(XMLUtils.java:595)
    at org.apache.axis2.util.XMLUtils.toOM(XMLUtils.java:575)
    at org.apache.axis2.deployment.DescriptionBuilder.buildOM(DescriptionBuilder.java:97)
    at org.apache.axis2.deployment.AxisConfigBuilder.populateConfig(AxisConfigBuilder.java:91)
    at org.wso2.carbon.core.CarbonAxisConfigurator.populateAxisConfiguration(CarbonAxisConfigurator.java:308)
    at org.wso2.carbon.core.CarbonAxisConfigurator.getAxisConfiguration(CarbonAxisConfigurator.java:188)
    at org.apache.axis2.context.ConfigurationContextFactory.createConfigurationContext(ConfigurationContextFactory.java:64)
    at org.wso2.carbon.core.CarbonConfigurationContextFactory.createNewConfigurationContext(CarbonConfigurationContextFactory.java:65)
    at org.wso2.carbon.core.init.CarbonServerManager.initializeCarbon(CarbonServerManager.java:398)
    at org.wso2.carbon.core.init.CarbonServerManager.start(CarbonServerManager.java:219)
    at org.wso2.carbon.core.internal.CarbonCoreServiceComponent.activate(CarbonCoreServiceComponent.java:77)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.ds.model.ServiceComponent.activate(ServiceComponent.java:260)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.ds.model.ServiceComponentProp.activate(ServiceComponentProp.java:146)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.ds.model.ServiceComponentProp.build(ServiceComponentProp.java:347)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.ds.InstanceProcess.buildComponent(InstanceProcess.java:620)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.ds.InstanceProcess.buildComponents(InstanceProcess.java:197)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.ds.Resolver.getEligible(Resolver.java:343)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.ds.SCRManager.serviceChanged(SCRManager.java:222)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.serviceregistry.FilteredServiceListener.serviceChanged(FilteredServiceListener.java:107)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.BundleContextImpl.dispatchEvent(BundleContextImpl.java:861)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.eventmgr.EventManager.dispatchEvent(EventManager.java:230)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.eventmgr.ListenerQueue.dispatchEventSynchronous(ListenerQueue.java:148)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.serviceregistry.ServiceRegistry.publishServiceEventPrivileged(ServiceRegistry.java:819)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.serviceregistry.ServiceRegistry.publishServiceEvent(ServiceRegistry.java:771)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.serviceregistry.ServiceRegistrationImpl.register(ServiceRegistrationImpl.java:130)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.serviceregistry.ServiceRegistry.registerService(ServiceRegistry.java:214)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.BundleContextImpl.registerService(BundleContextImpl.java:433)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.http.servlet.internal.Activator.registerHttpService(Activator.java:81)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.http.servlet.internal.Activator.addProxyServlet(Activator.java:60)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.http.servlet.internal.ProxyServlet.init(ProxyServlet.java:40)
    at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.servlet.DelegationServlet.init(DelegationServlet.java:38)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.initServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1284)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.loadServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1197)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.load(StandardWrapper.java:1087)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.loadOnStartup(StandardContext.java:5229)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5516)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1575)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1565)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:262)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: javax.xml.stream.XMLStreamException: ParseError at [row,col]:[31,21]
Message: Invalid byte 1 of 1-byte UTF-8 sequence.
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLStreamReaderImpl.next(XMLStreamReaderImpl.java:596)
    at org.apache.axiom.util.stax.wrapper.XMLStreamReaderWrapper.next(XMLStreamReaderWrapper.java:225)
    at org.apache.axiom.util.stax.dialect.SJSXPStreamReaderWrapper.next(SJSXPStreamReaderWrapper.java:138)
    at org.apache.axiom.om.impl.builder.StAXOMBuilder.parserNext(StAXOMBuilder.java:681)
    at org.apache.axiom.om.impl.builder.StAXOMBuilder.next(StAXOMBuilder.java:214)
    ... 49 more
Carbon Server WSO2 Carbon 4.2 based server at localhost is shutting down...
Carbon Server WSO2 Carbon 4.2 based server at localhost has shutted down...
```

Comment: What are your steps you went through to get this error? Please describe your problem in more detail

Comment: I didn't do much.  I brought up the server, used the tool to generate data services and was able to access them via soapUI.  Then  didn't touch anything for a few days and when booted back up the server would not start up again giving this error.  I then tried to get the newest Java version but wso2 does not support Java 1.8 so I disabled that version on windows.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like /repository/conf/axis2/axis2.xml has a non-compatible character, most probably at the line mentioned.

Comment: Seems like somehow there were quote characters that were not really quotes around a parameter in the Axis2. I used XML Spy to highlight the offending characters.  The quote characters were so close to the actual quotes I would never have seen them.  Thanks Chamila for pointing me at the Axis2.xml file.