# WSO2 Carbon Initialization Failed (Fatal Error)

Tags: authentication, wso2, wso2-identity-server

I have installed WSO2 Identity Server on my machine which is running Windows 10. I am trying to start the server using the command `wso2server.bat --run`, however I get the error `WSO2 Carbon initialization Failed`. The following is the complete log from the terminal:-

```
C:\Users\USER\Downloads\wso2is-5.4.0\bin>wso2server.bat --run
JAVA_HOME environment variable is set to C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_152
CARBON_HOME environment variable is set to C:\Users\USER\Downloads\wso2is-5.4.0
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM warning: ignoring option MaxPermSize=256m; support was removed in 8.0
[2017-12-21 13:57:30,161]  INFO {org.wso2.carbon.core.internal.CarbonCoreActivator} -  Starting WSO2 Carbon...
[2017-12-21 13:57:30,161]  INFO {org.wso2.carbon.core.internal.CarbonCoreActivator} -  Operating System : Windows 10 10.0, amd64
[2017-12-21 13:57:30,161]  INFO {org.wso2.carbon.core.internal.CarbonCoreActivator} -  Java Home        : C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_152\jre
[2017-12-21 13:57:30,161]  INFO {org.wso2.carbon.core.internal.CarbonCoreActivator} -  Java Version     : 1.8.0_152
[2017-12-21 13:57:30,161]  INFO {org.wso2.carbon.core.internal.CarbonCoreActivator} -  Java VM          : Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM 25.152-b16,Oracle Corporation
[2017-12-21 13:57:30,161]  INFO {org.wso2.carbon.core.internal.CarbonCoreActivator} -  Carbon Home      : C:\Users\USER\Downloads\wso2is-5.4.0
[2017-12-21 13:57:30,161]  INFO {org.wso2.carbon.core.internal.CarbonCoreActivator} -  Java Temp Dir    : C:\Users\USER\Downloads\wso2is-5.4.0\tmp
[2017-12-21 13:57:30,161]  INFO {org.wso2.carbon.core.internal.CarbonCoreActivator} -  User             : USER, en-US, Asia/Calcutta
[2017-12-21 13:57:31,067]  INFO {org.wso2.carbon.event.output.adapter.kafka.internal.ds.KafkaEventAdapterServiceDS} -  Successfully deployed the Kafka output event adaptor service
[2017-12-21 13:57:31,129]  INFO {org.wso2.carbon.event.processor.manager.core.internal.util.ManagementModeConfigurationLoader} -  CEP started in Single node mode
[2017-12-21 13:57:32,676]  INFO {org.wso2.carbon.ldap.server.configuration.LDAPConfigurationBuilder} -  KDC server is disabled.
[2017-12-21 13:57:47,505]  INFO {org.wso2.carbon.mex.internal.Office365SupportMexComponent} -  Office365Support MexServiceComponent bundle activated successfully..
[2017-12-21 13:57:47,505]  INFO {org.wso2.carbon.mex2.internal.DynamicCRMCustomMexComponent} -  DynamicCRMSupport MexServiceComponent bundle activated successfully.
[2017-12-21 13:57:49,897]  INFO {org.wso2.carbon.user.core.ldap.ReadWriteLDAPUserStoreManager} -  LDAP connection created successfully in read-write mode
[2017-12-21 13:57:53,287]  INFO {org.wso2.carbon.registry.core.jdbc.EmbeddedRegistryService} -  Configured Registry in 59ms
[2017-12-21 13:57:53,350]  INFO {org.wso2.carbon.registry.core.internal.RegistryCoreServiceComponent} -  Registry Mode    : READ-WRITE
[2017-12-21 13:57:53,365]  INFO {org.wso2.carbon.attachment.mgt.server.internal.AttachmentServiceComponent} -  Initialising Attachment Server
[2017-12-21 13:57:53,738]  INFO {org.wso2.carbon.attachment.mgt.core.dao.impl.jpa.AbstractJPAVendorAdapter} -  [Attachment-Mgt OpenJPA] DB Dictionary: h2
[2017-12-21 13:57:53,738]  INFO {org.wso2.carbon.attachment.mgt.core.dao.impl.jpa.AbstractJPAVendorAdapter} -  [Attachment-Mgt OpenJPA] Generate DDL Enabled.
[2017-12-21 13:57:53,988]  INFO {org.wso2.carbon.identity.authenticator.x509Certificate.internal.X509CertificateServiceComponent} -  X509 Certificate Servlet activated successfully..
[2017-12-21 13:57:54,738]  INFO {org.wso2.carbon.attachment.mgt.server.internal.AttachmentServiceComponent} -  Registering AttachmentServerService
[2017-12-21 13:57:55,738]  INFO {org.wso2.carbon.bpel.core.internal.BPELServiceComponent} -  Initializing BPEL Engine........
[2017-12-21 13:57:55,847]  INFO {org.wso2.carbon.bpel.core.ode.integration.BPELServerImpl} -  Using DAO Connection Factory class: org.apache.ode.dao.jpa.BPELDAOConnectionFactoryImpl
[2017-12-21 13:57:56,035]  INFO {org.wso2.carbon.bpel.core.ode.integration.BPELServerImpl} -  Registering E4X Extension...
[2017-12-21 13:57:56,035]  INFO {org.wso2.carbon.bpel.core.ode.integration.BPELServerImpl} -  Registering B4P Extension...
[2017-12-21 13:57:56,035]  INFO {org.wso2.carbon.bpel.core.ode.integration.BPELServerImpl} -  Registering B4P Filter...
[2017-12-21 13:57:56,050]  INFO {org.wso2.carbon.bpel.core.ode.integration.BPELServerImpl} -  Registering MBeans
[2017-12-21 13:57:56,128]  INFO {org.wso2.carbon.humantask.core.internal.HumanTaskServiceComponent} -  Initialising HumanTask Server
[2017-12-21 13:57:56,160]  INFO {org.wso2.carbon.humantask.core.dao.jpa.AbstractJPAVendorAdapter} -  [HT OpenJPA] DB Dictionary: h2
[2017-12-21 13:57:56,160]  INFO {org.wso2.carbon.humantask.core.dao.jpa.AbstractJPAVendorAdapter} -  [HT OpenJPA] Generate DDL Enabled.
[2017-12-21 13:57:56,191]  INFO {org.wso2.carbon.humantask.core.internal.HumanTaskServiceComponent} -  Registering Axis2ConfigurationContextObserver
[2017-12-21 13:57:56,191]  INFO {org.wso2.carbon.humantask.core.internal.HumanTaskServiceComponent} -  Registering HT related MBeans
[2017-12-21 13:57:56,206]  INFO {org.wso2.carbon.humantask.core.internal.HumanTaskServiceComponent} -  MXBean for Human tasks registered successfully
[2017-12-21 13:57:56,347]  INFO {org.wso2.carbon.metrics.impl.util.JmxReporterBuilder} -  Creating JMX reporter for Metrics with domain 'org.wso2.carbon.metrics'
[2017-12-21 13:57:56,363]  INFO {org.wso2.carbon.metrics.impl.util.JDBCReporterBuilder} -  Creating JDBC reporter for Metrics with source 'Lenovo-PC', data source 'jdbc/WSO2MetricsDB' and 60 seconds polling period
[2017-12-21 13:57:56,378]  INFO {org.wso2.carbon.metrics.impl.reporter.AbstractReporter} -  Started JDBC reporter for Metrics
[2017-12-21 13:57:56,378]  INFO {org.wso2.carbon.metrics.impl.reporter.AbstractReporter} -  Started JMX reporter for Metrics
[2017-12-21 13:58:43,732]  INFO {org.wso2.carbon.registry.indexing.solr.SolrClient} -  Default Embedded Solr Server Initialized
[2017-12-21 13:58:44,076]  INFO {org.wso2.carbon.user.core.internal.UserStoreMgtDSComponent} -  Carbon UserStoreMgtDSComponent activated successfully.
[2017-12-21 13:58:45,232]  INFO {org.wso2.carbon.identity.user.store.configuration.deployer.UserStoreConfigurationDeployer} -  User Store Configuration Deployer initiated.
[2017-12-21 13:58:45,232]  INFO {org.wso2.carbon.identity.user.store.configuration.deployer.UserStoreConfigurationDeployer} -  User Store Configuration Deployer initiated.
[2017-12-21 13:58:45,263]  INFO {org.wso2.carbon.bpel.deployer.BPELDeployer} -  Initializing BPEL Deployer for tenant -1234.
[2017-12-21 13:58:45,263]  INFO {org.wso2.carbon.humantask.deployer.HumanTaskDeployer} -  Initializing HumanTask Deployer for tenant -1234.
[2017-12-21 13:58:46,935] FATAL {org.wso2.carbon.core.init.CarbonServerManager} -  WSO2 Carbon initialization Failed
org.apache.axiom.om.OMException: com.ctc.wstx.exc.WstxIOException: Invalid UTF-8 middle byte 0x3f (at char #2621, byte #-1)
        at org.apache.axiom.om.impl.builder.StAXOMBuilder.next(StAXOMBuilder.java:296)
        at org.apache.axiom.om.impl.llom.OMDocumentImpl.getOMDocumentElement(OMDocumentImpl.java:109)
        at org.apache.axiom.om.impl.builder.StAXOMBuilder.getDocumentElement(StAXOMBuilder.java:570)
        at org.apache.axiom.om.impl.builder.StAXOMBuilder.getDocumentElement(StAXOMBuilder.java:566)
        at org.apache.axis2.util.XMLUtils.toOM(XMLUtils.java:592)
        at org.apache.axis2.util.XMLUtils.toOM(XMLUtils.java:575)
        at org.apache.axis2.deployment.DescriptionBuilder.buildOM(DescriptionBuilder.java:97)
        at org.apache.axis2.deployment.AxisConfigBuilder.populateConfig(AxisConfigBuilder.java:91)
        at org.apache.axis2.deployment.DeploymentEngine.populateAxisConfiguration(DeploymentEngine.java:887)
        at org.apache.axis2.deployment.FileSystemConfigurator.getAxisConfiguration(FileSystemConfigurator.java:116)
        at org.apache.axis2.context.ConfigurationContextFactory.createConfigurationContext(ConfigurationContextFactory.java:64)
        at org.apache.axis2.context.ConfigurationContextFactory.createConfigurationContextFromFileSystem(ConfigurationContextFactory.java:210)
        at org.wso2.carbon.core.init.CarbonServerManager.getClientConfigurationContext(CarbonServerManager.java:573)
        at org.wso2.carbon.core.init.CarbonServerManager.initializeCarbon(CarbonServerManager.java:458)
        at org.wso2.carbon.core.init.CarbonServerManager.removePendingItem(CarbonServerManager.java:291)
        at org.wso2.carbon.core.init.PreAxis2ConfigItemListener.bundleChanged(PreAxis2ConfigItemListener.java:118)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.BundleContextImpl.dispatchEvent(BundleContextImpl.java:847)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.eventmgr.EventManager.dispatchEvent(EventManager.java:230)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.eventmgr.EventManager$EventThread.run(EventManager.java:340)
Caused by: com.ctc.wstx.exc.WstxIOException: Invalid UTF-8 middle byte 0x3f (at char #2621, byte #-1)
        at com.ctc.wstx.sr.StreamScanner.constructFromIOE(StreamScanner.java:625)
        at com.ctc.wstx.sr.StreamScanner.loadMore(StreamScanner.java:997)
        at com.ctc.wstx.sr.StreamScanner.getNext(StreamScanner.java:754)
        at com.ctc.wstx.sr.BasicStreamReader.nextFromProlog(BasicStreamReader.java:2000)
        at com.ctc.wstx.sr.BasicStreamReader.next(BasicStreamReader.java:1134)
        at org.apache.axiom.om.impl.builder.StAXOMBuilder.parserNext(StAXOMBuilder.java:681)
        at org.apache.axiom.om.impl.builder.StAXOMBuilder.next(StAXOMBuilder.java:214)
        ... 18 more
Caused by: java.io.CharConversionException: Invalid UTF-8 middle byte 0x3f (at char #2621, byte #-1)
        at com.ctc.wstx.io.UTF8Reader.reportInvalidOther(UTF8Reader.java:314)
        at com.ctc.wstx.io.UTF8Reader.read(UTF8Reader.java:212)
        at com.ctc.wstx.io.ReaderSource.readInto(ReaderSource.java:87)
        at com.ctc.wstx.io.BranchingReaderSource.readInto(BranchingReaderSource.java:57)
        at com.ctc.wstx.sr.StreamScanner.loadMore(StreamScanner.java:991)
        ... 23 more
```

I referred to the following question: [wso2 app server (carbon) startup error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31249001/wso2-app-server-carbon-startup-error), however that did not help me much. Please advise me as to how I should run the WSO2 server.

Answer (score 1):

Try following.

1. Stop the WSO2 Server.
2. add `-Dfile.encoding=UTF8` under  CMD_LINE_ARGS in `wso2server.bat` file.
3. Restart the Server.

Also, note that JDK 8u152 has [a known gzip bug](https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8189789) which causes failures in WSO2 products. Use 8u144 instead.

Comment: The line you suggested already exists in the file. Do you know where I could get JDK 8u144? I checked the official site, but it has JDK 9, 8u151 and 8u152. As far as I know, 8u144 has expired.

Comment: http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/java-archive-javase8-2177648.html However, if you don't want to use JDK8u144, you can disable gzip compression in `repository/conf/tomcat/catalina-server.xml`

Btw, Did you make any configuration changes?

Comment: No, I didn't make any configuration changes. I'll try to disable gzip compression. How do I do so?

Comment: Set `compression="off"`

Comment: I did as you said, but I'm still getting the same error.

Comment: By the way, I changed my JDK to 8u144, but I'm still getting the same error. How do I solve this issue? I think I should mention, I had downloaded the source code from GitHub and built the new folder myself.

Comment: Can you try downloading from the product download page and see how it goes? https://wso2.com/identity-and-access-management

Comment: Yeah, I'll try that out. Thing is, I wanted to access the source code.

Comment: Yeah, I downloaded the built product from the Product Download page, and it's running fine. I don't know if I had made a mistake while trying to build it from the source code with Maven. Anyway, thanks for your help!